# Smartphone programming

Tags: smartphone

I have been tasked to develop an application for my school that should be usable by smartphones.
Now, I have never done any smartphone programming so there is a lot of research to be done regarding well, everything.

So, my question here is, if I have to develop an application with no specific smartphone in mind, what would the most generic kind then be?

Second, I am looking for some reading material where I can get an understanding of the common aspects of the various smartphones so that I can pick the tools to work with, that are generic across smartphones. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lowest barrier to entry for this project, consider using HTML/JavaScript and running it (at first) as a web page. Then, if you decide this is the path you want to take, use PhoneGap (or similar) to create native apps from your existing work.

Comment: Had made a java application at first to test it out on my computer and had hoped i could just use that but was prepared to go HTLM/JS way as that was also the thing i saw as most generic.
Wanted to make sure, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May not be at the exact 'generic' level you are looking for, but the 'Mono' project may be worth a look.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Its a commercial project allowing developers to create production code in C#/.Net, and use the Mono framework to deploy to cross platforms such as Macs, iphones, andriods etc..

I would agree with the above that HTML/CSS coded for the respective browsers using mobile resolutions would be the easiest way to go - but should you really wish to have a native application instead of a web-app, then Mono could be useful to you.